# intel hd graphics- framebuffer not complete?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an application which I usually run on Nvidia graphics card. I thought I'd try running it on the Sandy Bridge Intel HD Graphics 3000.

However, when I'm running on the intel hardware I get an "framebuffer not complete" from the following initialization code:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo_);        
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fbo_);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);
glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE_ARB); 
// Error: "the object bound to FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_EXT is not "framebuffer complete"
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You kinda need [at least one color attachment](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html#check) (before [OpenGL 4.3 at least](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Empty_framebuffers)).

[More info.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Completeness)