# Framebuffer not complete! using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer

I cloned the following example:

https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/tree/master/src/5.advanced_lighting/6.hdr

```
git clone https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL
cd LearnOpenGL
echo "static char const * logl_root = \".\";" > includes/learnopengl/root_directory.h
cp -avr resources src/5.advanced_lighting/6.hdr
cd src/5.advanced_lighting/6.hdr
g++ -std=c++11 hdr.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lm -lglfw3 -lpthread -lX11 -lXrandr -lXinerama -lXi -lXxf86vm -lXcursor -lGL -ldl -lSOIL -lassimp  -I ../../../includes
```

Which compiles fine. But it has problem in running. The output in command line window is

```
./a.out
Framebuffer not complete!
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
exposure: 1
```

The output is a dark window.

How should I fix it?

I do not follow the installation guides as they lead to some other errors and finally they stop. So far many examples has worked for me by manual building. But this HDR example has `Framebuffer not complete!` problem.

[Link to hdr.cpp](https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/blob/master/src/5.advanced_lighting/6.hdr/hdr.cpp)

hdr.cpp

```
// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// GL includes
#include <learnopengl/shader.h>
#include <learnopengl/camera.h>

// GLM Mathemtics
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

// Other Libs
#include <SOIL.h>
#include <learnopengl/filesystem.h>

// Properties
const GLuint SCR_WIDTH = 800, SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

// Function prototypes
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void Do_Movement();
GLuint loadTexture(GLchar const * path);
void RenderScene(Shader &shader);
void RenderCube();
void RenderQuad();

// Camera
Camera camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f));

// Delta
GLfloat deltaTime = 0.0f;
GLfloat lastFrame = 0.0f;

// Options
GLboolean hdr = true; // Change with 'Space'
GLfloat exposure = 1.0f; // Change with Q and E

// Global variables
GLuint woodTexture;

// The MAIN function, from here we start our application and run our Game loop
int main()
{
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Set the required callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    // Options
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT);

    // Setup some OpenGL options
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Setup and compile our shaders
    Shader shader("lighting.vs", "lighting.frag");
    Shader hdrShader("hdr.vs", "hdr.frag");

    // Light sources
    // - Positions
    std::vector<glm::vec3> lightPositions;
    lightPositions.push_back(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 49.5f)); // back light
    lightPositions.push_back(glm::vec3(-1.4f, -1.9f, 9.0f));
    lightPositions.push_back(glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.8f, 4.0f));
    lightPositions.push_back(glm::vec3(0.8f, -1.7f, 6.0f));
    // - Colors
    std::vector<glm::vec3> lightColors;
    lightColors.push_back(glm::vec3(200.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f));
    lightColors.push_back(glm::vec3(0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    lightColors.push_back(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.2f));
    lightColors.push_back(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f));

    // Load textures
    woodTexture = loadTexture(FileSystem::getPath("resources/textures/wood.png").c_str());

    // Set up floating point framebuffer to render scene to
    GLuint hdrFBO;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &hdrFBO);
    // - Create floating point color buffer
    GLuint colorBuffer;
    glGenTextures(1, &colorBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // - Create depth buffer (renderbuffer)
    GLuint rboDepth;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboDepth);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT);
    // - Attach buffers
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, hdrFBO);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer, 0);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);
    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        std::cout << "Framebuffer not complete!" << std::endl;
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);

    // Game loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Set frame time
        GLfloat currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        // Check and call events
        glfwPollEvents();
        Do_Movement();

        // 1. Render scene into floating point framebuffer
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, hdrFBO);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(camera.Zoom, (GLfloat)SCR_WIDTH / (GLfloat)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
            glm::mat4 view       = camera.GetViewMatrix();
            glm::mat4 model;
            shader.Use();
            glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
            glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "view"),       1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, woodTexture);
            // - set lighting uniforms
            for (GLuint i = 0; i < lightPositions.size(); i++)
            {
                glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, ("lights[" + std::to_string(i) + "].Position").c_str()), 1, &lightPositions[i][0]);
                glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, ("lights[" + std::to_string(i) + "].Color").c_str()), 1, &lightColors[i][0]);
            }
            glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "viewPos"), 1, &camera.Position[0]);
            // - render tunnel
            model = glm::mat4();
            model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 25.0));
            model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(5.0f, 5.0f, 55.0f));
            glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
            glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "inverse_normals"), GL_TRUE);
            RenderCube();
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);      

        // 2. Now render floating point color buffer to 2D quad and tonemap HDR colors to default framebuffer's (clamped) color range
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);        
        hdrShader.Use();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(hdrShader.Program, "hdr"), hdr);
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(hdrShader.Program, "exposure"), exposure);
        RenderQuad();       

        std::cout << "exposure: " << exposure << std::endl;

        // Swap the buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}


// RenderQuad() Renders a 1x1 quad in NDC, best used for framebuffer color targets
// and post-processing effects.
GLuint quadVAO = 0;
GLuint quadVBO;
void RenderQuad()
{
    if (quadVAO == 0)
    {
        GLfloat quadVertices[] = {
            // Positions        // Texture Coords
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        };
        // Setup plane VAO
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &quadVAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &quadVBO);
        glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadVBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quadVertices), &quadVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    }
    glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

// RenderCube() Renders a 1x1 3D cube in NDC.
GLuint cubeVAO = 0;
GLuint cubeVBO = 0;
void RenderCube()
{
    // Initialize (if necessary)
    if (cubeVAO == 0)
    {
        GLfloat vertices[] = {
            // Back face
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom-left
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-right         
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // top-right
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom-left
            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,// top-left
            // Front face
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-left
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom-right
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // top-right
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // top-left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom-left
            // Left face
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // top-right
            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // bottom-left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // bottom-left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom-right
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // top-right
            // Right face
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // top-left
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // bottom-right
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-right         
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // bottom-right
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // top-left
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-left     
            // Bottom face
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-left
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,// bottom-left
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-right
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
            // Top face
            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,// top-left
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-right
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-right     
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-right
            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,// top-left
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f // bottom-left        
        };
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &cubeVBO);
        // Fill buffer
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        // Link vertex attributes
        glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
    // Render Cube
    glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

// This function loads a texture from file. Note: texture loading functions like these are usually 
// managed by a 'Resource Manager' that manages all resources (like textures, models, audio). 
// For learning purposes we'll just define it as a utility function.
GLuint loadTexture(GLchar const * path)
{
    // Generate texture ID and load texture data 
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    int width, height;
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image(path, &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
    // Assign texture to ID
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_SRGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // Parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    return textureID;

}

bool keys[1024];
bool keysPressed[1024];
// Moves/alters the camera positions based on user input
void Do_Movement()
{
    // Camera controls
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_W])
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(FORWARD, deltaTime);
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_S])
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(BACKWARD, deltaTime);
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_A])
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(LEFT, deltaTime);
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_D])
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(RIGHT, deltaTime);

    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_SPACE] && !keysPressed[GLFW_KEY_SPACE])
    {
        hdr = !hdr;
        keysPressed[GLFW_KEY_SPACE] = true;
    }

    // Change parallax height scale
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_Q])
        exposure -= 0.5 * deltaTime;
    else if (keys[GLFW_KEY_E])
        exposure += 0.5 * deltaTime;
}

GLfloat lastX = 400, lastY = 300;
bool firstMouse = true;
// Is called whenever a key is pressed/released via GLFW
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);

    if (key >= 0 && key <= 1024)
    {
        if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
            keys[key] = true;
        else if (action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        {
            keys[key] = false;
            keysPressed[key] = false;
        }
    }
}

void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    if (firstMouse)
    {
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    GLfloat xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    GLfloat yoffset = lastY - ypos;

    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    camera.ProcessMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset);
}

void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    camera.ProcessMouseScroll(yoffset);
}
```

Comment: Please see if this QA is useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242953/intel-hd-graphics-framebuffer-not-complete

Comment: @vcp thanks for your link. I have seen this question. It needs an expert to understand this answer. I have just used `opengl` today

Comment: @vcp, BTW, it seems `hdr.cpp` has no attachment problem according to line 115 to 118. My guess is more on missing a resource.

Comment: How useful is this question if Joey ever moves his repository? Don't link to code. Embed it into the question. If it's too much code, then [whittle it down to a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check the actual status code returned from `glCheckFramebufferStatus`. It will give more detail about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really enough information here to diagnose the problem, so you need to do some debugging.  The first suspect would be whether your OpenGL implementation supports using a `GL_RGB16F` texture as a framebuffer attachment.  You might try changing that to `GL_RGBA16F` and seeing if that works.

Beyond that, I would suggest adding some additional logging during initialization...

Right before

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer, 0);
```

add

```
std::cout << "Color buffer: " << colorBuffer << std::endl;
std::cout << "Depth buffer: " << rboDepth << std::endl;
```

So that you can verify that the color buffer and depth buffer are valid (non-zero) before the framebuffer attachments occur.  Additionally, I would change

```
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    std::cout << "Framebuffer not complete!" << std::endl;
```

to

```
auto fboStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (fboStatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    std::cout << "Framebuffer not complete: " << fboStatus << std::endl;
```

So that you can see the actual frame buffer status, which may give you a clue as to the problem.

It might also be a good idea while you're learning to put a glGetError() call after every OpenGL call to make sure you didn't generate an error...

```
{
    auto glstatus = glGetError();
    if (glstatus != GL_NO_ERROR) { std::cout << "Error in GL call: << glstatus << std::endl; } 
}
```

Comment: `Color buffer: 2`, `Depth buffer: 1` , `Framebuffer not complete: 36061`

Comment: also try this condition `if (fboStatus == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED)
        std::cout << "implementation is not supported by OpenGL driver " << fboStatus << std::endl;`

Comment: Thanks a lot. changing `GL_RGB16F` to `GL_RGBA16F` fixed the problem.

Comment: The window after fixing changed from absolute dark to [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IcLp3.png) thanks a lot.

Comment: I sometimes get 36061 error which is GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED, could you please help to see why? does the NVidia card has configuration problem? how can I check why this happens? the image format problem?